# Get ffmpeg png output as stream (not a png file)

Tags: image, ffmpeg, stream, output

In VB.NET I'm creating sound file waveform with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x240:split_channels=1" -frames:v 1 output.png
```

this code works good. But i have no write rights on pc at all and i can't create output.png anywhere. i must to get output.png as stream and put to picturebox as background image.

can someone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Basic method is

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "..." -frames:v 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe -
```

This will stream the result over stdout.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found an article about my question. http://blog.wudilabs.org/entry/c3d357ed  but i can't handle image.  how can i get image ? can you help me please?

Comment: Is there any way to get multiple images via pipe? Not all at once, but each frame separately.

Comment: What do you mean 'separately' - in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get a thumbnail from a video. The following code in C# is used to return the image as the response of a Web API.

```
public IActionResult VideoThumbnail([FromBody] JObject jObject)
{
    dynamic obj = jObject;
    var url = obj.path.ToString();

    FileStream stream = GetThumbnail(url) as FileStream;

    return File(stream, "image/bmp");
}

public static Stream GetThumbnail(string url)
{
    var cmd = "ffmpeg  -itsoffset -1  -i " + '"' + video + '"' + " -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 -";

    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/C " + cmd,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        Stream stream = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
        process.WaitForExit(5000);

        return stream;
    }
}
```